# Problems With a Simple Driving Game

Tags: python, pygame, trigonometry

I'm trying to make a simple top down driving simulator where you hold down the up arrow key to move and use the right/left arrow keys to steer.  Ideally, if you were to hold down the up key and left or right key at the same time, the car would move in a circle.

The car should move the same distance on the screen each frame, regardless of the direction.  I devised a set of equations to calculate the x and y coordinates with a given direction (in degrees).  It treats each movement like a right triangle.  The hypotenuse is the set distance the car will move regardless of the direction.  The other two sides are the x and y values required to achieve the specific hypotenuse length.  It uses the cosine function to find one side, and Pythagorean's theorem to find the last side.

I tested it on graph paper and it does move the same distance each time regardless of the direction.  The problem is that the car does not move in a circle (if you keep steering).  The default direction is 0 degrees, so when you hold the up key the car will move straight up.  If you start turning clockwise (right arrow key) the car will start curving to the right.  But at a certain point it will not move in a circle.  Try running the code and it will make sense.

*the direction is converted to radians because that is what python uses

```
import pygame, math

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 700))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# The center of the sceen
x = 475
y = 325

drive = 0  # 0 = not moving, 1 = moving
turn = 0   # 1 = clockwise, -1 = counter-clockwise

d = 0

def move(d, c):
    d = math.radians(d)
    a = math.cos(d) * c
    b = math.sqrt((c**2) - (a**2))

    return a, b


def main():
    while True:
        global x, y, drive, turn, d
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    drive = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    turn = 1
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    turn = -1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    drive = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    turn = 0
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    turn = 0


        if drive == 1:
            if turn == 1 and d != 359: # Turn Clockwise
                d += 4
            if turn == 1 and d == 359:
                d = 0
            if turn == -1 and d != 0: # Turn Counter Clockwise
                d -= 4
            if turn == -1 and d == 0:
                d = 359


        ''' move()[0]  =  a
            move()[1]  =  b '''
        if drive == 1:
            if d >= 0 and d < 90:
                x += move(d, 6)[1]
                y -= move(d, 6)[0]


            if d >= 90 and d < 180:
                x += move(d-90, 6)[0]
                y += move(d-90, 6)[1]


            if d >= 180 and d < 270:
                x -= move(d-90, 6)[1]
                y += move(d-90, 6)[0]


            if d >= 270 and d < 360:
                x -= move(d-180, 6)[1]
                y += move(d-180, 6)[0]



        screen.fill((40,40,40))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), (round(x, 0), round(y, 0), 50, 50))


        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(20)


main()
```

Comment: In your code, what will happen if `d > 360` or `d < 0`?  I imagine this happens a lot because, for example, `d += 4` will never equal 359 and thus if you turn clockwise enough, `d > 360`.

Comment: I didn't realize that.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention.  It won't move at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following on my comment above, it looks like if you change:

```
    if drive == 1:
        if turn == 1 and d != 359: # Turn Clockwise
            d += 4
        if turn == 1 and d == 359:
            d = 0
        if turn == -1 and d != 0: # Turn Counter Clockwise
            d -= 4
        if turn == -1 and d == 0:
            d = 359
```

to

```
    if drive == 1:
        if turn == 1 and d < 359: # Turn Clockwise
            d += 4
        if turn == 1 and d >= 359:
            d = 0
        if turn == -1 and d > 0: # Turn Counter Clockwise
            d -= 4
        if turn == -1 and d <= 0:
            d = 359
```

it doesn't stop moving.  However, your rules could be ***drastically*** simplified.  Use the full power of the trigonometric functions by updating your x,y coordinates directly with `cos/sin` since `sin(-y) = -sin(y)` and `cos(-x) = cos(x)`.  Your whole script could look like:

```
def main():
    # define these here since you aren't modifying them outside of main
    x = 475
    y = 325
    drive = 0  # 0 = not moving, 1 = moving
    turn = 0   # 1 = clockwise, -1 = counter-clockwise
    # set to -90 since 0 points east.
    d = -90

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    drive = 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    turn = 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    turn = -1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    drive = 0
                elif event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_LEFT):
                    turn = 0

        if drive == 1:
            d += turn * 4

            x += 6 * math.cos(math.radians(d))
            y += 6 * math.sin(math.radians(d))

        screen.fill((40,40,40))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,255), (round(x, 0), round(y, 0), 50, 50))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(20)
```

Comment: Thank you!  This really helps a lot.  It works perfectly, but I don't quite understand the line that says d += turn * 4.  Also, why is east 0 degrees instead of North?